# Bytes a String en Python 3

Tags: python

Estoy en un trabajo con un cifrador: hasta ahí todo va bien, pero necesito pasar la llave como cadena para guardarla en un txt. El problema es que la cadena se genera más o menos así

> b'|\x918\x8c\xeaQ\xe5\xb6\xfeC\xa4\xb5/\xc2T\xbc\xc82u\xf1\xd5\xce,I'

Y yo necesito que esté así

> |\x918\x8c\xeaQ\xe5\xb6\xfeC\xa4\xb5/\xc2T\xbc\xc82u\xf1\xd5\xce,I

Es decir pasar de un byte string o bytes a una cadena común y corriente.

He intentado con coders; buscando alguna ayuda por ahí solo sugieren `str.decode('utf-8')` pero al hacer eso da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y poniéndole el utf-8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La generación de llave es el siguiente código

```
while True:
    try:
        key = DES3.adjust_key_parity(get_random_bytes(24))
        archivo = open("key.txt","w")
        sample_string_bytes = str(key).encode("ascii")
        base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(sample_string_bytes)
        base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
        archivo.write(base64_string)
        archivo.close()
        print("Llave creada con exito")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Llave creada sin exito")
        pass

 print(key.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Una aclaración preliminar

El problema es que la "cadena" que quieres guardar contiene bytes que realmente no son interpretables como caracteres (corresponderían a caracteres no imprimibles en ascii).

Cuando vuelcas una cadena de bytes por pantalla, Python tiene que mostrarla de alguna forma imprimible, por lo que elige mostrar como `\xXX` cada byte que daría lugar a un ASCII no imprimible siendo `XX` el valor hexadecimal del byte en cuestión. Pero eso no significa que la cadena de bytes contenga realmente `\xXX` en su interior, es sólo la forma en la que python lo muestra.

Es decir, imagina que tu "cadena" contiene 4 bytes y que éstos 4 bytes serían en binario los siguientes:

```
00000001 01000001 01111000 11000010'
```

Esos cuatro bytes si los escribo en hexadecimal son:

```
01 41 78 c2
```

Y resulta que de los cuatro, el primero y el último no son ascii válidos, pero los dos del medio sí (y serían el ascii de la "A" y de la "x" respectivamente). Si intentaras imprimir una cadena de bytes que contenga esa información python te la mostraría así:

```
b'\x01Ax\xc2'
```

La `b` delante de las comillas es para recordarte que se trata de una cadena de bytes y no una "normal". Los tres primeros caracteres `\x01` son una forma de representar lo que en realidad es un solo byte, de valor 01. La `A` que aparece después es una forma de representar el siguiente byte, de valor 41, la `x` que va después es una forma de representar el siguiente byte, de valor 78 y finalmente la secuencia que va después `\xc2` es una forma de representar el último byte de valor c2

Python también habría podido elegir mostrarlo todo con el "formato `\x`" y haber por tanto volcado `b'\x01\x41\x78\xc2'`. Esta es también una representación *perfectamente válida* de la **misma cadena**.

De hecho, si haces lo siguiente en tu programa:

```py
bytes = b'\x01\x41\x78\xc2'
print(bytes)
```

verás que muestra `b'\x01Ax\xc2'`. No es que python haya cambiado de ninguna forma lo que habías asignado, es sólo que elige mostrarlo de otra forma.

Lo importante aquí es que, no importa como la representes, la cadena subyacente tiene solo 4 bytes y esos tienen los valores 01, 41, 78, c2.

### Tu pregunta

Ahora dices que quieres volcar eso como una cadena "común y corriente" y la verdadera pregunta es aquí ¿qué entiendes tú por una cadena así?

- ¿Una cadena que contenga solo ascii? A priori no es posible porque parte de los bytes no corresponden a caracteres ascii válidos y otros no son imprimibles.
- Una cadena que reemplace cada ascii no imprimible por una secuencia tipo `\x` tal como hace python para mostrarla? Puedes obtener eso con:

  ```
  archivo.write(repr(bytes)[2:-1])
  ```

  Aquí `repr()` te devuelve la representación que python hace de esa cadena de bytes. Esa representación es un string, y con el slice le quitamos el inicio y el final, quedando sólo con lo de dentro: "\x01Ax\xc2"
- Otra forma de representarlo? Puedes por ejemplo convertir cada byte interno a un par de dígitos hexadecimales y concatenarlos todos:

  ```
  archivo.write("".join(f"{v:02x}" for v in bytes))
  ```

  y eso volcaría al archivo la cadena "014178c2"
- Puedes también volcarlo como base64, pues precisamente el objeto con que este formato de representación fue inventado fue el de convertir cualquier secuencia de bytes arbitraria a una secuencia de caracteres que sólo contenga dígitos y letras (y un par de símbolos más). Eso lo harías así:

  ```py
  archivo.write(str(base64.b64encode(bytes), "ascii"))
  ```

  y volcaría al archivo la cadena "AUF4wg==" la cual, lo creas o no, es otra forma de representar la secuencia de bytes 01, 41, 78, C2

Naturalmente, el que elijas una u otra forma para generar una cadena "equivalente" te obligará a implementar también una forma correcta de leerla para volver a recuperar la secuencia de bytes orginales. En este sentido la opción más sencilla puede ser base64, ya que Python también tiene la función inversa:

```
>>> print(base64.b64decode('AUF4wg=='))
b'\x01Ax\xc2'
```

pero dependiendo de tu escenario particular podrías ser más apropiado otro mecanismo.